# transparent button

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Is there a way to make a button transparent without alpha?

To explain: I have a background image on my view. There is also a button with an image background. If the image has a transparent part I see white inside the button's background image.

Is it possible to make the image transparent?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the button type to 'Custom', either in code with: `UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` or in IB on the Attributes pane, under Button -> Type -> Custom.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `backgroundColor` of the button to `[UIColor clearColor]` and optionally its `opaque` to `NO` (Should automatically be applied by setting the background color to transparent).

Comment: Not work in this way but I find a solution in internet, I have to set   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; But however thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the button `opaque` property to `NO`.

In InterfaceBuilder, you have a checkbox to do that.